# Sum Integer and Show The Result to TextBox using C#

Tags: c#

I got some problem when summing integer and show the result to `TextBox` using C#. When I run my code, the result that is shown just the result of `lim30den50tot`. I want to sum `lim30den50tot`, `lim60den50tot`, etc. How can I do that ?

```
private int lim30den50tot;
private int lim60den50tot;
private int lim150den50tot;
private int lim450den50tot;
private int lim600den50tot;


private void JumlahLembar()
{
    int lim30 = 0;
    int lim60 = 0;
    int lim150 = 0;
    int lim450 = 0;
    int lim600 = 0;

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in JadwalisiGV.Rows)
    {

        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {


            OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();

            kon.Open();
            command.CommandText = "select * from [StokLembar$] where [Limit] = " + row.Cells["Limit"].Value;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int den50 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 50"].ToString());
                int den100 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 100"].ToString());

                if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "30")
                {
                    lim30++;
                    lim30den50tot = lim30 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                }

                else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "60")
                {
                    lim60++;
                    lim60den50tot = lim60 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                }

                else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "150")
                {
                    lim150++;
                    lim150den50tot = lim150 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                }

                else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "450")
                {
                    lim450++;
                    lim450den50tot = lim450 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                }

                else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "600")
                {
                    lim600++;
                    lim600den50tot = lim600 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                }


               TotalDen50Box.Text = (lim30den50tot + lim600den50tot + lim150den50tot + lim450den50tot + lim600den50tot).ToString();
              }  
            kon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `TotalDen50Box.Text` outside your loop because you are overwrite it in every iteration of the loop. Also your integer value should be sum from current value plus previous one, if you want to show the sum for all rows. Example `lim30den50tot += lim30 * 2 * den50 * 50000;`

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //stuff

    if(condition)
    {
        lim30den50tot += lim30 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
    }
    else if(condition2)
         //do the same for other ints
}

TotalDen50Box.Text = (lim30den50tot + lim600den50tot + lim150den50tot + lim450den50tot + lim600den50tot).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you show the results in each loop. You have to just put `TotalDen50Box.Text = (lim30den50tot + lim600den50tot + lim150den50tot + lim450den50tot + lim600den50tot).ToString();` outside the loop:

```
private int lim30den50tot;
private int lim60den50tot;
private int lim150den50tot;
private int lim450den50tot;
private int lim600den50tot;


private void JumlahLembar()
{
     int lim30 = 0;
     int lim60 = 0;
     int lim150 = 0;
     int lim450 = 0;
     int lim600 = 0;

     foreach(DataGridViewRow row in JadwalisiGV.Rows)
     {

         if (!row.IsNewRow)
         {


             OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
             OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();

             kon.Open();
             command.CommandText = "select * from [StokLembar$] where [Limit] = " + row.Cells["Limit"].Value;
             OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 int den50 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 50"].ToString());
                 int den100 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 100"].ToString());

                 if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "30")
                 {
                     lim30++;
                     lim30den50tot += lim30 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                 }

                 else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "60")
                 {
                     lim60++;
                     lim60den50tot += lim60 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                 }

                 else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "150")
                 {
                     lim150++;
                     lim150den50tot += lim150 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                 }

                 else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "450")
                 {
                     lim450++;
                     lim450den50tot += lim450 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                 }

                 else if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "600")
                 {
                     lim600++;
                     lim600den50tot += lim600 * 2 * den50 * 50000;
                 }



             }  
             TotalDen50Box.Text = (lim30den50tot + lim600den50tot + lim150den50tot + lim450den50tot + lim600den50tot).ToString();
             kon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```